# foreach $row within a while loop

Tags: php

I am trying to create a calendar:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   while ( $day_num <= $days_in_month ){ 

  //echo "<td style='background-color:red;' onclick='testing(this)'> $day_num </td>"; 

   echo "<td  onclick='testing(this)'> $day_num </td>";
   $day_num++; 
   $day_count++;
   if ($day_count > 7){
      echo "</tr><tr>";
      $day_count = 1;
   }
 }
}
```

The code is working fine, the issue I am having is I want to change the background of days that are in the database. As I see it, I need to put a foreach in there to check each

```
$row['day']
```

check

```
if($day_num == $row['day']) {
```

and put my commented out echo in there, but no matter where I place the foreach it breaks.

Can anyone tell me how to best go about this?

Comment: Please be more clear.  _want to change the background of days that are in the database_?   Also your query is not working fine,  it`s prone to a **SQL INJECTION**.  Use **prepared statements** and pre sanitize user submitted data.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will be reworking it, and will keep that in mind as I do so.

And the next time I post a question I will try to be more in-depth.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
echo "<td " . ( $day_num == $row['day'] ? 'style="background-color:red;" ' : ' ' ) . "onclick='testing(this)'> $day_num </td>";
```

It checks whether `$day_num` is equal to `$row['day']` and outputs the additional styling if so, and just a space if not.

Comment: As I re-read your code, though, I think your `while()` loops are backwards. You want to output the table cells regardless of the database result set. You probably need to operate two separate while() loops. The first to build an array of days in the database, the second to output each calendar week and compare whether the date is inside the array of days you build in the first.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for, clearly the way I am going about it is improper, and was trying to figure out how best to go about it.

The code chunk you provided caused Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':'

I think the flow is just screwed up, will rework.

Comment: That is my mistake, the `?` and `:` were in backwards positions :) Have updated my answer